# Generating a sequence of $n$-bit random-like numbers that will never repeat.

Tags: random

I am actually aiming for n $\approx 100$ but obviously I could interleave the bits of two never-repeating $50$-bit sequences etc.

I need to be able to generate the $n^{th}$ number quickly enough to seem instantaneous to a human. After that, finding the $(n+1)^{th}$ should be trivial.

Given a large number of the already generated numbers I need it to be difficult to reproduce the algorithm I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't generate a list of $n$ bit numbers that never repeats because there are only $2^n$ of them.  It must repeat within that time.

Probably the easiest way to generate them is to use some very simple random number generator like a linear congruential one, and hash the result.

Added:  A [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) seems to do what you want.  You could build one in software of length $100$ bits.  It will avoid all collisions.  It looks like predicting the output from a number of successive outputs is quite easy, but you could run it through your favorite encryption algorithm.  The Advanced Encryption Standard has a version that outputs 128 bits.  If that is too many, you could find a pair of 49/50 bit primes and do [RSA encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_encryption)

Comment: I plan to stop well before the last number, probably around 1/2 way through, certainly well before my algorithm becomes obvious. - What do you mean by *and hash the result*?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon:  to take the output of your random number generator (which will be easy to guess if you give somebody lots of values) and run it through a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function_%28cryptography%29)  You could also run it through your favorite encryption algorithm.

Comment: I am limited to 100 bits of output so hashing would almost certainly introduce duplicates would it not?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon If you have a cycle of $2^{100}$ and you stop half way through, you'll have gone through $2^{99}$ numbers. If you can do one billion ($1000000000$) every second, that will take a little over twenty trillion years :-)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon:  You would expect a collision at about $2^{100/2}=2^{50}\approx 10^{15}$ outputs.  You could use a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) to make sure of no duplicates, but I don't know how easy they are to crack.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez - that is **exactly** what I am looking for. I may end up with thousands of generators each starting at their own spot but none must **ever** produce the same number that one of the others has or will.

Comment: @RossMillikan - There must never be any collisions, and with this wide a field I am not going to be able to record all previous numbers to detect a duplicate. Thus my need for a non-repeating algorithm.

Comment: @RossMillikan - If you could post a separate answer for the LFSR idea I will up-vote. I could choose a number of different ones and interleave the bits. There is more discussion required however because I need to be able to generate the nth number in the sequence.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon:  Then I would just find my favorite encryption algorithm.  The [Advanced Encryption Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) has a version that outputs $128$ bits.  Is that too many more than $100$?

Comment: @RossMillikan - I would happily discard 28 bits so long as the result never repeats.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon:  But you can't guarantee the result will not repeat.  See my edit, suggesting you can use RSA to get output the size you want.